# Disabling or enabling chrome causes my android app in background to crash when resumed

Tags: android, onresume, background-foreground

steps:

Opened my android app -> put it to background

Opened chrome app info -> click disable app -> put it to background

Resumed my android app from background -> app loses static variables and object set before it went to background.

Normal cases -> going back and resuming working fine.

It would be great if someone could let me know the root cause and solution.

Below is my code for basefragment which is extended by other fragments, where data gets lost or UI thread is terminated.

```
 @Override
public final View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                               ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    checkPresenter();
    mParentFragmentView = createEmbeddedDialogFragmentView(onCreateViewImpl(layoutInflater, container, savedInstanceState), layoutInflater, savedInstanceState);
    mParentFragmentView.setClickable(true);
    launchThread();
    return mParentFragmentView;
}

private void launchThread() {
    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            initFragment(mParentFragmentView);
            loadData();
        }
    };

    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100);
}


protected abstract void loadData();

protected abstract void initFragment(View parentView);
```

Here on loadData() (overriden by child fragment) gets some data saved in an object which is lost. Also, I am using a Custom logger (static) class, whose settings (a dynamically set object (set on splash activity) also lost. As a result, I am getting either "null pointer" or "Invocation target exception". This is a legacy project and is working perfect in other scenarios. Please suggest.